# Converting from cfg to cnf (Chomsky normal form)

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

I am trying to convert this grammar from context free grammar with kleene star productions into the Chomsky normal form equivalent. I am having a hard time trying to understand how to do this, I need this for use in recursive decent parsers primarily a table driven top down predictive parser.

Grammar

> expr        ::= term {addop term} 
>   term    ::= factor {mulop factor} 
>   factor     ::= variable| unsigned-number| ( expr)
>    variable ::= identifier 
>   addop ::= + | - 
>   mulop ::= * | /

Comment: Why do you need CNF to produce a recursive descent parser? Once you know the grammar is LL(1), you can just turn each production directly into RD parsing code. (Use a `while` loop to translate the Kleene stars, which are not technically part of the CFG rules.)

Comment: Okay, could you expand upon what you were saying? I do not really understand how you are supposed to do this and then get the same. The grammar from my knowledge is ll(1) but I just dont get how you would implement the kleene star with the while and be able to predict what production to use and how to use it with a table driven setup.